# How to binding Textbox1 To Textbox2 in Vb.net

Tags: sql, visual-studio, data-binding, binding, textbox

2008, i want binding txtEmpNo To txtFullName. but i checked column it's correct.

**Error** "Cannot bind to the property or column [First Name] on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember"

**This Code:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim da3 As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds3 As New DataSet()
            Dim bs2 As New BindingSource()

            Dim sql As String = "SELECT Employee.[First Name] From Employee WHERE Employee.EmployeeNo = '" & txtEmpNo.Text.ToString & "'"
            da3 = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
            da3.Fill(ds3, "Employee")

            If ds3.Tables("Employee").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                txtFullName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds3, "Employee.[First Name]"))
                txtFullName.DataBindings.Clear()
            Else
                txtFullName.Text = ""
            End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataMember` parameter (the 3rd one) should only be the name of the column.
The correct table in the DataSet should be passed in the 2nd parameter.  In other words, change your binding to this:

```
txtFullName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds3.Tables("Employee"), "First Name"))
```